# Why short-lived, not short-living?

Tags: meaning

Can you, please, try to explain why dictionaries know "short-lived", but not short-living?
e.g. I believe I've heard: "mind the **closing** doors" in the subway. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases where you would use the idiom "short-lived" it wouldn't make *logical* sense to say 'short living', never mind grammatical.

If something is *living*, it is still alive, so the length of its life cannot be measured. We say '*short-lived*' to describe something that has ended after only a short time, eg "*his success was short-lived*". You couldn't say about someone currently enjoying success that it is short because it isn't over yet.

We can also say it about something that is *known* to be short; for example some might plaintively remark that "*man's time on earth is short-lived*" to mean that *in general*, humans have relatively short or limited lives. You could describe a species in general as being "short-living" but remember that "short" is always relative, so you have to be clear what you are comparing it to. Many animal species have short lives compared to humans, but humans have short lives compared to certain species that routinely outlive us.

"*Mind the closing doors*" is a warning to be careful of automatic doors *as they are closing*, because you could get a limb trapped in them or something. It would make no sense to warn people about *closed* doors. I suppose someone could walk into a closed door but such a person is unlikely to take note of a warning sign telling them not to, either.

Comment: But what if a length of life is yet to be measured :) e.g. for a housefly life expectancy is 15-30 days. If we mention that fact in a discussion, than for any given fly which is alive, we know for sure that its life will be short, but the fly is still alive. Would "a short-living insect" sound off then?

Comment: @westandskif Yes, I believe I answered that in my third paragraph. You could say, of the housefly in general, that its life is short-lived. But you're not saying it about a *specific, living* housefly. Maybe that specific one buzzing round your kitchen will live 33 days.. that's 10% longer than most of its peers. 'Short-lived' describes a *relatively* short time. You could agree that humans have a short life compared to some types of trees and turtles, but a specific person living to 110 would be considered as having a long life!

Comment: **Also**, short-lived is an actual adjective. And so is closing in your example. The opening night was yesterday.

Comment: @lambie "short-living" is also be an adjective. If you can make a legitimate hyphenated compound it's an adjective. Perhaps you mean its not an idiom. I don't know what your point is about 'closing' - of course it's an adjective, that's the point of this - to explain why the tense is logical in the context.

Comment: @Astralbee - well, it does exist and the OED has one attestation: "*Ye know this world is but a shadow, a short-living creature, under the law of time*." S. Rutherford, Lett. (1664) 372.  Despite that, it seems a bit odd today. I suppose "short-lived" won out in the end. As to why? Merely due to common usage, there doesn't appear to be any real logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about this answer, but I'll tell what it *appears* to be:

Often we use the construction "[adjective] [noun]+ed" as one big adjectival phrase, like "short haired" dogs or cats, or "sure-footed" mountain goats. If we were to follow this pattern, it would be "short-lifed." It appears that this really is the etymology of the idiom. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/short-lived):

> From *short* +‎ *lived* (“having a life, lifed”), equivalent to *short* +‎ *life* +‎ *-ed*. Compare Middle English *short-livi*, *sort-levi* (“short-lived”). ... The pronunciation /ʃɔɹtˈlaɪvd/ (the second syllable rhyming with *hived*) is more consistent with the etymology (since the term comes from the noun *life* rather than the verb *live*), and was formerly more common; however, the pronunciation /ʃɔɹtˈlɪvd/ (the second syllable pronounced as the verb *lived*) is more common today.

That would make this idiomatic phrase a bit of an outlier, and has a lot to do with the blurriness in etymology and pronunciation between "life," "live" (the verb), and "live" (the adjective). (Not to mention *lithe*...)